# How I can define and arrange following linear equation?

Tags: equation-solving, wolfram-alpha-queries

We have:

```
Theta * (2L-K) = 0 Theta cannot be zero because it's angle parameters.
(2L-K)=0 then We can calculate L=K/2
```

How we can define this constraint in Wolfram|Alpha or online wolfram?

Comment: `Simplify[Theta*(2 L - K) == 0, Theta != 0]`?

Comment: @kglr yes this is the right, IS there any link that I can test it online?

Comment: MK you can try  [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) or  [wolfram cloud app](https://develop.open.wolframcloud.com/app/)

Comment: would u please post it as an answer @kglr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Simplify[Theta*(2 L - K) == 0, Theta != 0]
```

> K == 2 L